# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '40 1 3 4 20\n'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Programming challenge description:

> Alice has invented a new card game to play with Bob. Alice made a deck
> of cards with random values between 1 and 52. Bob picks 5 cards. Then,
> he has to rearrange the cards so that by utilizing the operations
> plus, minus, or times, the value of the cards reach Alice's favorite
> number, 42. More precisely, find operations such that:
>
> `((((val1 op1 val2) op2 val3) op3 val4) op4 val5) = 42`

```
import sys
import itertools
Numbers=[]
i=0
for line in sys.stdin:
    # print(line, end="")
    Numbers.append(int(line))
    i=i+1
    if(i==5):
        break


Operators=['+','-','*','+','-','*'] #we can be use 4 operator from this

#file all the posible permutations
lst1=list(itertools.permutations(Numbers,5))
lst2=list(itertools.permutations(Operators,4))

result = False
for x in lst1:
    for op in lst2:
        str1=str(x[0])+op[0]+str(x[1])
        str2=str(str1)+op[1]+str(x[2])
        str3=str(str2)+op[2]+str(x[3])
        str4=str(str3)+op[3]+str(x[4])
        exp=eval(str4) #solve the expression

        if(exp==42):
            result = True
            break
    if(result==True):
        break

if(result==True):
    print("\nYES")
else:
    print("\nNO")
```

Using an online IDE to run this but getting an error. Please tell me where I made the mistake.
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/source.py", line 8, in <module>
    Numbers.append(int(line))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '40 1 3 4 20\n'
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly where you made a mistake: `line` is the string `'40 1 3 4 20\n'`. That string cannot be interpreted as _one_ integer, as `int(line)` is trying to do.

Comment: It's complaining about the spaces in your string. You may want to turn it into an array of numbers by trying something like `Numbers.extend([int(seg) for seg in line.split()])`

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the input incorrectly. Try this:

```
Numbers = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.read().strip().split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument you are passing to the `int` function is a string with spaces and so it can't be converted to a string. If you want to add all the numbers in the line in the array, you can do -

```
Numbers.extend(list(map(int, line.split())))
```

Comment: Doing it. I believe I just have to change this only?

Comment: Glad I could help!